# Zookeeper unable to listen on port 3888

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, apache-zookeeper

I've got 3 servers on aws. each with open jdk 7 and zookeeper 3.4.6 all have unique elastic ip's.
each conf/zoo.cfg has

- clientPort=2181
- server.1=server1:2888:3888
- server.2=server2:2888:3888
- server.3=server3:2888:3888

then i start it with ./zkServer.sh start (says STARTED)
and the zookeeper.out says

```
2015-01-14 09:27:55,919 [myid:1] - INFO  [Thread-1:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@504] - My election bind port: /server1ipaddress:3888
2015-01-14 09:27:55,920 [myid:1] - ERROR [/server1ipaddress:3888:QuorumCnxManager$Listener@517] - Exception while listening
    java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
            at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:330)
            at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager$Listener.run(QuorumCnxManager.java:507)
```

So it cant open the port. 
i've eventually opened all ports on aws security to rule that out.

- telnet into 2181 with ruok gets imok.
- telnet into 2888 cannot connect. connection refused.
- telnet into 3888 cannot connect. connection refused.

netstat shows that nothing is blocking 2888 and 3888

i've even tried this with all 3 servers having zookeeper started. 
whats going on? how do i get those ports open for use.

Comment: i think i solved it. i used the internal AWS IP's for the server list in zoo.cfg
now on ./zkServer.sh status i get leader & follower on the other 2

Comment: How you fixed the issue? Same issue for me

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940981/zookeeper-error-cannot-open-channel-to-x-at-election-address/30993130#30993130?newreg=08fbe3fd0a464f8ebaf41b598b19f2dc).

In a few words: on each ZooKeeper machine, at your `conf/zoo.cfg`, you have to set the current server's IP to `0.0.0.0`.
For example: if you are currently on server1, the config should contain the following lines:

```
server.1=0.0.0.0:2888:3888
server.2=server2:2888:3888
server.3=server3:2888:3888
```

This step solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Cross verify myid's on all the nodes based on the zoo.cfg. The same issue happened to me, upon looking myid pattern got changed on 2 of the nodes.